Directory.Build.props only respected when building .sln file
When I build my projects with the MyConfig target, I want the code to be optimized, and I don't want any .pdb files.
To achieve this, I have created a Directory.Build.props file like this in the root of my project.
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;MyConfig</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'MyConfig|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>none</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

Now, if I run this command, I get the expected output:
dotnet build .\BuildPoc.sln -c MyConfig

However, when building the project directly:
dotnet build .\src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj -c MyConfig

Then the .pdb files are created.
I do no understand why there is a difference?
Should dotnet build not respect the Directory.Build.props regardless?
I have created a sample repository here with a simple project displaying this behaviour: https://github.com/mortenbock/BuildPoc
EDIT:
Additionally, I just discovered, that if I run these two commands:
dotnet build .\BuildPoc.sln -c MyConfig
dotnet publish .\src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj -c MyConfig --no-build

Then I get this error, where it seems the dotnet publish assumes there should be a .pdb file?
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(351,5): error MSB3030:
 Could not copy the file "obj\MyConfig\net8.0\MyProject.pdb" because it was not found. [D:\Projects\BuildPoc\sr
c\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]


Both your build and publish issues get resolved by passing an explicit  platform argument via -p:Platform=AnyCPU.

Building the project:

dotnet build .\src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj -c MyConfig -p:Platform=AnyCPU


Publishing the project:

dotnet publish .\src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj -c MyConfig --no-build -p:Platform=AnyCPU


Alternatively, remove the $(Platform) check from the condition, since all your commandlines have -c MyConfig.
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'MyConfig'">

For now, I haven't found an official explanation.

An other alternative exists in using a Directory.Build.targets file, which gets imported later.
As from your comment, the order of imports and evaluations matters.
You can rename that Directory.Build.props file to Directory.Build.targets.
When doing so your initial attempt for building the project will work.
dotnet build .\src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj -c MyConfig

To get the project published, you have to both build and publish it in one go, so removing the --no-build (or use the previous/above publish suggestion).
dotnet publish .\src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj -c MyConfig


I went with the alternative of changing my conditions.
It's very strange though. I tried outputting the $(Platform) during the build, and it was AnyCPU in both cases, but maybe it's about at which point in the build that value is set?
Could be that sometimes it's not set until after the conditions are evaluated.

I followed similar steps that you mention, even a --verbosity detailed didn't make me much wiser.

Directory.Build.props is imported very early and before the 'common' project support. Unless there is a clear need, avoid using Directory.Build.props and prefer Directory.Build.targets. (The names are arbitrary. Both files are "full" MSBuild files with no restrictions, i.e. properties don't need to be in .props.)

The presumption in the title "Directory.Build.props only respected when building .sln file" is not correct and is not what is happening.
A Directory.Build.props is imported very early and before the 'common' project support. The $(Configuration) and $(Platform) properties are defined in the 'common' project support after the content of the Directory.Build.props.
Defining Configuration and/or Platform at the command line changes that. The properties on the command line will be defined as global properties before the Directory.Build.props is imported.
With a solution file, MSBuild first 'translates' the solution into a 'meta project'. The meta project builds each project in the solution passing a Configuration and Platform from the solution.
The default value for Configuration is Debug.
All of the projects in the BuildPoc.sln solution have "Any CPU" as the Platform. Since there is only one Platform in use, it will be the default.
(The sln meta project will map "Any CPU" in the solution to "AnyCPU" for projects.)
Why does dotnet build .\BuildPoc.sln -c MyConfig work? Because the sln is providing values for Configuration and Platform to the project.
Why does dotnet build .\src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj -c MyConfig not work? Because in the project, common properties including Configuration and Platform are defined after the Directory.Build.props is imported. With the -c switch The value of $(Configuration)|$(Platform) is MyConfig| when the PropertyGroup Condition is evaluated and the DebugType, Optimize, and DefineConstants properties are not changed. (This is also the cause of the MSB3030 error when running publish against the project.)
You can confirm by adding the following to the Directory.Build.props:
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TraceConfiguration Condition="'$(Configuration)' == ''">Configuration has no value.</TraceConfiguration>
    <TraceConfiguration Condition="'$(Configuration)' != ''">Configuration has the value '$(Configuration)'.</TraceConfiguration>
    <TracePlatform Condition="'$(Platform)' == ''">Platform has no value.</TracePlatform>
    <TracePlatform Condition="'$(Platform)' != ''">Platform has the value '$(Platform)'.</TracePlatform>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="ShowPropsTrace" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="*** $(TraceConfiguration)"/>
    <Message Text="*** $(TracePlatform)"/>
  </Target>

As a rule of thumb, avoid using Directory.Build.props and prefer using Directory.Build.targets. It is rare and unusual to have an actual need for the very early import of Directory.Build.props.
The Directory.Build.props and Directory.Build.targets names are arbitrary. Both files are "full" MSBuild files with no restrictions, i.e. properties don't need to be in .props.
See "How MSBuild builds projects" and note the evaluation and execution phases.
The simple fix for the solution and project is to rename the Directory.Build.props file to Directory.Build.targets.
Since the compiler properties are related only to the Configuration, it would be a good idea to only test the Configuration.
